# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/HASYv2/hasy-data/hasy-data

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run this code :

## Preparing training data as numpy array of vectors from raw images

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io, color
base = "/content/HASYv2/hasy-data/"
listOfB = []
for items in df['path'].iteritems(): 
    pil_im = Image.open(base +items[1], 'r')
    array1 = np.asarray(pil_im)/255.
    listOfB.append(array1)
B = np.array(listOfB) 
B.reshape(1826, 32, 32, 3)
B.shape
```

and I have this error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/HASYv2/hasy-data/hasy data/v2-00345.png'
Thanks

Comment: Does that path exist?  It looks like you're double-counting "hasy-data" with "hasy data"

Comment: What is the output of this `base +items[1]` . Does this match the exact location?